# Autocomplete list getting hidden due to another component below it

Tags: android

As mentioned in the title, my autocomplete textview suggestion list is getting hidden when I have a mapview just below it. I have commented the mapview in the below code and checked and it shows the autocomplete list. What need to be done in order that the the list is shown on top of the mapview below it?

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.test.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/atv_places"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/candidate_white_bg"
    android:hint="@string/str_atv_places"
    android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How about using a RelativeLayout, and adding the auto complete list after/on top of the map?

Comment: how will i set the weight then proportionately as above?

Comment: My thought was to keep the Text input float over the map so as not to get cut, but will fill the screen only when the list is to be displayed,

Answer (score 1):

You could try using z-order(`mAutocompleteTextView.bringToFront();`, [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront%28%29))
If doesn't work - try using same with RelativeLayout

Comment: `bringToFront()` brought the autocomplete textview to the bottom of the layout

Comment: @user264953 There are other methods of playing with z-order. Try plaing with them